# Angularjs to assign $scope to preexisting MVC model data

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

So I'm using ASP.NET with MVC 5. I have a Model called 'Employee' which holds a 'FirstName' value. I have a list of Employees, and I'm trying to use angular to grab all of the 'FirstName's in Employee and just simply display them in a list.

I'm assuming I would need a scope to do this, so how can I assign all of the FirstName values to a scope?

Here's some code

```js
// Controller.js

var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []);
myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) { 
   $scope firstnames;
});
```

```html
Index.cshtml

@model IEnumerable<Test.Models.Employee>

<html ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <script>
            var nameArray = [];
            @foreach (var d in Model)
            {
              @:nameArray.push("@d.FirstName");
            }

            firstnames = nameArray;
        </script>

        <li ng-repeat="name in firstnames">
            {{name}}
        </li>
    </div>
</html>
```

So the script works in the sense that it collects all of the values successfully, except that I am unable to pass it to the scope.

I looked online and people were using $http or JSON serialization. I tried to implement some examples I saw, but to no avail. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

`<html>` with no `<body>` tag? Anyways, try doing your model pushing inside the actual controller code: (I'm changing `html` to `div`)

```
@model IEnumerable<Test.Models.Employee>

<div ng-app="myModule">
  <div ng-controller="myController">    
     <li ng-repeat="name in firstnames">
        {{name}}
     </li>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var myApp = angular.module('myModule', []);
  myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.firstnames = []
    @foreach (var d in Model)
    {
      @:$scope.firstnames.push("@d.FirstName");
    }  
  });
</script>
```